# Cache Control not Working in Firefox

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, firefox, cache-control

I want to set expire header for each resource files. I'm tried with resource mapping cache period.

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" cache-period="86400"/>
```

Its working in chrome and safari. But not working in Firefox

Also i'm tried with **another way** through Filters. As same problem - not working in Firefox.

```
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
    httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
    httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L);         
    chain.doFilter(request, response
```

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem with Lotus Notes and a web form. Firefox just doesn't follow the same rules as everyone else with cache-control.

My solution was to use javascript on the front end to emulate what I was trying to accomplish with cache-control.